# Augmented Reality cult short story - Infiltrating agent is won over

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I was thinking of a story that I read in a compilation a decade or so ago, likely one of those "Best of (Year)" ones.

In the story, there is a guy that is tasked with infiltrating a group of ascetics that live in, I think, the mountains, protected by a variety of autonomous security systems (I seem to remember sand-snake-robots in there somewhere). Apparently, these mountain folks were augmented by technology, and normally non-augmented people had issue with this and wanted to destroy them for reasons I can't exactly remember.

Anyway, in the end the protagonist manages to make it through the defenses, infiltrates the group, but ends up becoming augmented himself. He comes to realize the superiority of this way of life. Everyone walks around IRL wearing grey, featureless robes in a gray cave, but once augmented the AR overlays reveal a rich, colorful existence.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details.

Comment: Thanks, I will! Also, thanks to Valorum for the much better title.